# How to edit the list of named/defined colors?

Tags: customize, colors

How can I change (insert,delete,rename,…) the list of named colors?

I tried to edit `/usr/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/term/tty-colors.el.gz` and byte-compile after change, but it had no effect.

Note: I do **not** want to have another color picker, but change the builtin picker wich shows on `list-colors-display` or in Customization-context. I could live with an other color picker though, if it'd be very simmilar and also would replace the builtin color picker in every case…

<strike>Also I tried to get help on the variable `defined-colors` with `C-h v defined-colors RET`, but got no match - does that mean, there is just no help on this variable?</strike>
Edit: Ok, this is bec. it's a function – but `C-h f defined-colors RET` also doesn't contain info on where the defined colors are stored and how they might be adjusted.

EDIT1 (after comment by jue): Tried to insert `("testcolor" 35980 65535 0)` to `tty-colors.el.gz` and added "testcolor" at the end of the list `x-colors` in `common-win.el.gz`, byte-compiled both and restarted emacs - but still no "Testcolor" entry in *Colors*.

EDIT2 (after 2nd comment by jue): Only file named `rgb.txt` on my (arch linux) system is `/usr/share/emacs/25.3/etc/rgb.txt` I inserted `140 255 0 testcolor` there (+ EDIT1) - still no entry.

EDIT3 …well maybe my desire to use the builtin color picker isn't very smart – I'll rather look for a color picker, that presents colors in a similar way and isn't bound to some X11 system file. I'll update, when I find something sufficient.

Still feel free to answer this exact question (as I'd love to gather insight to emacs), or suggest a color picker, that presents just a user defined list of colored color value entries.

Comment: have a look at file `common-win.el`, there is a list and the function `xw-defined-colors` which is called by `defined-colors`.

Comment: ty, but I don't see, how to add i.e. #ff6600 with name "FF6600". The hint in code mentions some  `rgb.txt'-file - but I don't have a file named rbg.txt anywere

Comment: With X11 (Unix) colors are defined in `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt`.correct path might be slightly different  on distributions.

Comment: I did a `find / -iname rgb.txt` – there is no file rgb.txt, but the one in emacs' folder (see edit Q).

Comment: The above mentioned `rgb.txt` on my system, is a link and points to `/etc/X11/rgb.txt`. Emacs `list-colors-display`shows less colors  than listed in this file. Maybe have another look at `comon-win.el` or `faces.el`? Did you restart your X11 server after changes of edit 1 and 2? (I'm also just guessing, though)

Comment: On my system there only is that file (not a link), also no change on X-restart – I'll inspect the `comon-win.el` and `faces.el` more. Of course I'll update, should I succeed. But as this task seems fairly hard, I'll focus on finding (or writing if I don't find any) a color picer, which suits my needs.   TY for your help so far!

Comment: I had a look at Emacs  c-source code. Emacs is fetching color values by name, either through GTK or X11 functions. It depends what Emacs you are using. So if you are using GTK-emacs try to define colors within gtk config. GTK version (2 or 3) matters. After this check within emacs with e.g. `M-: (xw-color-values "white")` for white color. If you see your color RGB values then try to manipulate the `x-colors` value. (I did not test this, nor do I know how to define colors within GTK, though). Also have a look at `M-: (list-colors-display '("black" "DimGrey" "DimGray") nil nil)`.

Comment: The `M-:` are neat, thank you.

Will dive into GTK later ^^

Comment: "As of X.Org Release 7.4 rgb.txt is no longer included in the roll up release,[3] and the list is built directly into the server.[4] The optional module xorg/app/rgb contains the stand-alone rgb.txt file." (from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names]) …one mistery solved :)